# Discard an unapproved page checkin in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, versioning, version-history

Okay, I think I must be missing something obvious here.

I have a standard webpart page. Version control and publishing is turned on.

There are a number of previous versions. Currently, there is a current major version (let's say, version 10.0) which is published and viewable by all users.

However I have since checked the page out, made some edits, and checked in a couple of minor versions (10.1 and 10.2) which are not published, and only viewable by myself and approvers. So the version history is something like:

- 10.2   Minor edit
- 10.1   Minor edit
- 10.0   Current, published major version
- 9.0    Old version
- 8.0    Old version
- 7.2
- 7.1
- 7.0
  ...etc

My problem is this: I want to get rid of the edits I made in versions 10.2 and 10.1. So, the next time I go to edit the page, I should be editing as from version 10.0, not 10.2.

I assumed I could just delete these versions, but I can't see anywhere to do that (in the version history page, I can only View or Restore). If I go into 'view' for version 10.2, there is an option to delete this version, however when I try I get 'The item that you are trying to delete is the current welcome page and cannot be deleted'. But I'm not trying to delete the whole page, just the version?!

I have tried using the 'delete minor versions' button - doesn't do anything.

How do I get rid of versions 10.1 and 10.2?

**Edit**

To help sort this, i would also like to view previous versions in the browser - can this be done? In the version history, If i choose 'View' on a previous version, all I get is the page properties screen:

[image: page version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to **Restore** the 10.0 as the current welcome page and then it will become 10.3 and you'll be able to **Delete** both 10.1 and 10.2

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I tried restoring 10.0 and now I get 10.3, but 10.3 looks just like 10.2, which I don't understand. Think I need to check what each version looks like. Is there a way to preview old versions in the browser? Again, can't find how to do this... thanks!

Comment: Well, the **View** option in the version history should let you see the page as it was back at that version.

Comment: View doesnt seem to let me see the page, only it's properties - See my edited answer for a screenshot. Is it even possible to view previous versions of pages?